# How to properly test Android model (MVP) in simple game setup?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mvp

I am making a simple game and have some questions about model setup/testing! I am trying to follow a MVP pattern if possible.

The following is a simplified version of some of my model classes, mainly the ones dealing with "logic".

```
public class GameManager implements LocationManagerDelegate {

    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private BattleManager mBattleManager;

    public GameManager(Location initialLocation) {
        mLocationManager = new LocationManager(initialLocation, self);
        mBattleManager = new BattleManager();
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        mLocationManager.setLocation(location);
    }

    public void handleLocationAction(Action action) {
        if (action.type == BATTLE) {
            mBattleManager.startBattle();
        }
    }
}

public class LocationManager {

    private LocationManagerDelegate mDelegate;
    private Location mLocation;

    public LocationManager(Location initialLocation, LocationManagerDelegate delegate) {
        mLocation = initialLocation;
        mDelegate = delegate;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        mLocation = location;

        Action action = location.getRandomAction();

        mDelegate.handleLocationAction(action);
    }
}

public interface LocationManagerDelegate {
    void handleLocationAction(Action action);
}

public class BattleManager {

    public BattleManager() {
    }

    public void startBattle() {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

I'm interested in testing these classes correctly. I can easily test `LocationManager` and `BattleManager` - they are separate, and I can use mock interfaces for the delegates where needed (i.e. `LocationManagerDelegate`)

But what about `GameManager`? It creates concrete `LocationManager`/`BattleManager` instances in it's own class, so if I wanted to test the overall flow of logic from the classes using the `GameManager`, it will actually be testing `GameManager` as well as `LocationManager`/`BattleManager` logic. I can't figure out a clean way to split it up...

Maybe something like this is this more correct?

```
public class GameManager implements LocationManagerDelegate {

    private ILocationManager mLocationManager;
    private IBattleManager mBattleManager;

    public GameManager(Location initialLocation, ILocationManager locationManager, IBattleManager battleManager) {
        mLocationManager = locationManager;
        mLocationManager.setInitialLocation(initialLocation);
        mLocationManager.setDelegate(this);

        mBattleManager = battleManager;
        mBattleManager.setDelegate(this);
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        mLocationManager.setLocation(location);
    }

    public void handleLocationAction(Action action) {
        if (action.type == BATTLE) {
            mBattleManager.startBattle();
        }
    }
}

public interface ILocationManager {
    void setInitialLocation(Location initialLocation);
    void setDelegate(LocationManagerDelegate delegate);
    void setLocation(Location location);    
}

public class LocationManager implements ILocationManager {

    private LocationManagerDelegate mDelegate;
    private Location mLocation;

    public void setInitialLocation(Location initialLocation) {
        mLocation = initialLocation;
    }

    public void setDelegate(LocationManagerDelegate delegate) {
        mDelegate = delegate;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        mLocation = location;

        Action action = location.getRandomAction();

        mDelegate.handleLocationAction(action);
    }
}

public interface LocationManagerDelegate {
    void handleLocationAction(Action action);
}

public interface IBattleManager {
    void startBattle();
}

public class BattleManager implements IBattleManager {

    public void startBattle() {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Then wherever we actually create the `GameManager` instance, we do something like:

```
ILocationManager locationManager = new LocationManager();
IBattleManager battleManager = new BattleManager();
Location initialLocation = ...;

GameManager manager = new GameManager(initialLocation, locationManager, battleManager);
```

This would allow me to put in mock `LocationManager`/`BattleManager` objects, but may not be too great since this also exposes some of the the "inner workings" of the `GameManager` class. It shouldn't necessarily be public information that I need to pass in these other manager classes, etc...

So what's best to do? Any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you have two options here:

**1. Constructor Injection of Dependencies**

This is as you outline above.  The dependencies are created outside of the class and passed in when it is created.  This way you can pass in your mocks at testing time.  This is also how you would do it if you were using a dependency injection library such as Dagger.

**2. Make The Dependencies Package Private**

As the tests for a class live in the same package as the class itself they have access to package private variables.  In this case you would change the access level of your two dependencies:

```
public class GameManager implements LocationManagerDelegate {

    LocationManager mLocationManager;
    BattleManager mBattleManager;

    //...
}
```

Then from your test you are able to do something like:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    gameManager = new GameManager();
    gameManager.mLocationManager = locationMock;
    gameManager.mBattleManager = battleMock;
}
```

Both methods have tradeoffs of opening up the insides of the class under test. Personally I currently prefer to use constructor injection as I've already got my classes set up that way for DI.